# Puppeteer screenshot scrolls the page down and cuts off the top of the element

Tags: puppeteer

Using Puppeteer, I am trying to take a screenshot of a canvas element to get the image inside. Image 1 is what I want but image 2 is what I get. I have tried to arrow up on the page but page.screenshot just snaps it back to where Image 2 is.

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e37xc.png)
[What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fioLf.png)

Comment: What Operating System are you using? Why don’t you try using something else to take your screenshot?

Comment: 1. Please add your code for doing this screenshot to the question. 2. Have you tried to run the same code with `{headless: false}` option? What did it look like?